# Node.js Appium install fail

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

I tried to install Appium with command: `npm install -g appium@1.6.4-beta`

I am behind corporate proxy. So i set new proxy with:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

also i tried:

`--ignore_ssl` or `--proxy http://10.165.42.170:8080`

My soft:

```
Node.js: v4.6.0
node-gyp -v v3.4.0
npm v4.4.4
Windows 8.1
```

But i am getting this error in install:

```
C:\Project\taf>npm install -g appium@1.6.4-beta
npm WARN deprecated babel-core@5.8.24: Babel 5 is no longer being maintained. Up
grade to Babel 6.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated line-numbers@0.2.0: Copy its ~20 LOC directly into your code
 instead.
C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm\appium -> C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js

> appium-chromedriver@2.11.0 install C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver
> node install-npm.js

info Chromedriver Install Installing Chromedriver version '2.28' for platform 'w
in' and architecture '32'
info Chromedriver Install Opening temp file to write chromedriver_win32 to...
info Chromedriver Install Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.co
m/2.28/chromedriver_win32.zip...
RequestError: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.23.208:443
    at new RequestError (C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appiu
m\node_modules\request-promise\lib\errors.js:11:15)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\appium\node_modules\request-promise\lib\rp.js:60:32)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\n
ode_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\appium\node_modules\request\request.js:884:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:269:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1269:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.x (node_modules\appiu
m\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@2.11.0 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@2.11.0 install script 'node install-n
pm.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the appium-chromedriver p
ackage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install-npm.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs appium-chromedriver
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls appium-chromedriver
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JE11954\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-04T12_46_5
6_785Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing this error.I have struggled a lot to resolve this by installing different node version and npm versions etc. but no success.

I have installed appium through yarn as below steps:

1. Download yarn.exe file from https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases
2. Run that .exe file and install as per instructions.
3. Once installation is finished, Add bin folder of yarn installation to your 
   PATH
   i.e (In my machine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\")
4. Now run the below command :

   ```
   yarn global add appium
   ```

This will install appium in your machine.

If this also doesn't work one more suggestion i can give is as below:

In general if you install appium through npm or yarn what it will do is it will install all the packages that will come along with appium latest GUI version i.e appium 1.7.2 which means whatever the packages are getting installed through npm or yarn will also come along with GUI version of appium which is appium-desktop.Please follow the below instructions:

1. Install latest appium-desktop version from the link : https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.4.1
2. Now go to installation path of appium-desktop.In my machine below is the path :

   ```
   C:\Users\pawan.lingutla\AppData\Local\Programs\appium- 
   desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium
   ```
3. In this folder you will find all the packages that will come with npm installation of appium.

This is a workaround when you face issues while installing appium into node_modules via npm or yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Node / npm solved install issues for me.